# Nested macros and ##

Tags: c

From The C Programming Language, by KRC

> After
>
> ```
> #define cat(x, y)       x ## y
> ```
>
> the call `cat(var,  123)` yields `var123`.  However, the call
>   `cat(cat(1,2),3)` is undefined:  the  presence  of  `##`  prevents 
>   the  arguments  of  the  outer  call  from  being  expanded.  Thus  it
>   produces the token string   `cat  (  1  ,  2  )3` 
>   and `)3` (the catenation of the last token of the first argument with
>   the first token of the second)  is not a legal token.
>
> If a second level of macro definition is introduced,
>
> ```
> #define xcat(x, y)      cat(x,y)
> ```
>
> things  work  more  smoothly; `xcat(xcat(1,  2),  3)`  does  produce 
>   `123`,  because  the  expansion of `xcat` itself does not involve the
>   `##` operator.

What is the property of `##` that makes the difference between the two examples?

Why is the inner `cat(1,2)` in the first example not expanded, while the inner `xcat(1,2)` in the second example is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the (not-so-well-known) characteristics of the macro `##` operator that it inhibits further expansion of its arguments (it just considers them plain strings). An excerpt from the gcc pre-processor docs:

> ...As with stringification, the actual argument is not macro-expanded first...

That is, arguments to `##` are **not** expanded.

By implementing the additional indirection using your `xcat` macro you are working around the problem (A process that is called the *argument prescan* is jumping in and actually evaluates the resulting string twice)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why "By implementing the additional indirection using your xcat macro you are working around the problem"?

Comment: If it is true that "xcat(xcat(1,  2),  3) does produce 123", then each `xcat(a,b)` will be firstly expanded to `cat(a,b)` which is then to `a  ## b`. I guess the outer `xcat` is expanded first, followed by the inner `xcat`, so when ` ##` first appears, it will prevent any further expansion, and then why does it say that "xcat(xcat(1,  2),  3) does produce 123"?