# How to understand rescanning the replacement token sequence for more defined identifiers in case of # or ## in macros?

Tags: c

From The C Programming Language by KRC, about the operators # and ## in macro definition

> Two  special  operators  influence  the  replacement  process.  First,
>   if  an  occurrence  of  a  parameter in the replacement token sequence
>   is immediately preceded by #, string quotes (")  are  placed  around 
>   the  corresponding  parameter,  and  then  both  the  #  and  the 
>   parameter  identifier are replaced by the quoted argument. A \
>   character is inserted before each " or \  character  that  appears 
>   surrounding,  or  inside,  a  string  literal  or  character  constant
>   in  the  argument.
>
> Second, if the definition token sequence for either kind of macro
>   contains a ## operator, then  just after replacement of the
>   parameters, each ## is deleted, together with any white space on 
>   either  side,  so  as  to  concatenate  the  adjacent  tokens  and 
>   form  a  new  token.  The  effect  is  undefined if invalid tokens are
>   produced, or if the result depends on the order of processing of  the ##  operators.  Also,  ##  may  not appear at  the  beginning  or  end of a replacement token  sequence.
>
> In  both  kinds  of  macro,  **the  replacement  token  sequence  is 
>   repeatedly  rescanned  for  more  defined identifiers**. However, **once a
>   given identifier has been replaced in a given expansion,  it is not
>   replaced if it turns up again during rescanning**; instead it is left
>   unchanged.

I am having trouble understanding the last paragraph, especially the sentences in bold.

Could you rephrase it, and/or give some examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the snippet:

```
#define A   B + C
#define B   1
#define C   2

int k = A;
```

In this case first pass

will replace `A`:

```
int k = B + C;
```

The second pass will replace `B` and `C`

```
int k = 1 + 2;
```

Now consider another snippet:

```
#define A   B + C
#define B   A
#define C   A

int k = A;
```

Now the first pass will expand `A` once, as before:

```
int k = B + C;
```

The second will replace `B` and `C` as before:

```
int k = A + A;
```

But here it will stop, as `A` was already expanded before in the first pass.

Comment: Thanks. When `#define cat(x, y)       x ## y`, why does `cat(cat(1,2),3)` expand only to `cat  (  1  ,  2  )3` instead of `123`? When expanding the outer `cat`, `<replacement>` doesn't contain any `<identifier>` that has been defined previously, does it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975200/nested-macros-and

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase the first emphasized sentence: when the preprocessor 'sees' a new `#define <identifier> <replacement>` directive, it checks whether `<replacement>` contains `<identifier>`s that have been defined previously.

But if some identifier's replacement contains the same identifier, it's not replaced by the replacement and left for the compiler to process. This means you can't define recursive macros like this:

```
#define recursion(a) ((a)>0)?:recursion(a-1):(a)
```

If you then write:

```
printf("%d\n", recursion(3));
```

Then the expansion would have a call to `recursion(3-1)` and the compiler will treat it as a call to a nonexistent function.

Comment: Thanks. When `#define cat(x, y)       x ## y`, why does `cat(cat(1,2),3)` expand only to `cat  (  1  ,  2  )3` instead of `123`? When expanding the outer `cat`, `<replacement>` doesn't contain any `<identifier>` that has been defined previously, does it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975200/nested-macros-and